# PHP 5.5 > PHP 5.6 Upgrade Causing MySQL Issues?

Tags: php, mysqli, php-5.5, php-5.6

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have been searching high and low and have come up with little in terms of results, but I might not be wording my search properly.

I attempted to upgrade from PHP 5.5 to PHP 5.6 today and it broke all my sites that make use of MySQL (all other PHP-only code was fine).

I am not getting MySQL Errors, I do see the connection being established, but it appears the queries aren't hitting the MySQL server. Instead, it seems the queries are being printed on the screen, and they aren't actually being executed.

I have 2 examples

1:

[image: here]

2:

[image: here]

Example 1 should show a login form, and Example 2 should show a drop down box with users to select. The login form and drop down box have been drawn on screen, but they are either not populated correctly or populated with variable names instead of results.

I read through the [migration guide at PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php), even the notes about latin1 charset (mine are UTF8), but there isn't much there.

Is there something obvious I am missing or something I did not yet read? Or should I be digging deeper? The Apache & PHP logs didn't appear to show much. I'm running out of options as my google searches are coming up blank. Has anyone else experienced this before?

Switching to PHP 5.5 brought all the sites back to normal without the errors / issues above. Switching back to PHP 5.6 introduces the errors / issues above again, so I believe it is something specific to PHP 5.6, but I'm baffled at the fact it does the mysqli_connect without error.

Comment: Raise your debug level and see if something gets in the log? Also, check to see if errors are printed instead of being logged. You might be in a development environment/configuration.

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with mysql. your php code isn't executing and is being sent out as plain text.

Comment: Sorry Marc B, I should have worded it better, but I honestly couldn't even begin to figure out where the problem lied, so I was trying to be as descriptive as possible. I have a few static pages that do not pull from MySQL, and they worked fine after the upgrade. All my pages that pull from MySQL however, were broken (and I realize now that was a complete fluke / coincidence, just what I happened to notice at the time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem extends beyond SQL queries. Your first image shows PHP code being outputted. Are you sure your configuration hasn't changed, for example turning [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) off?

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I didn't realize there was a new config directory for 5.6 or it didn't click. I remember very clearly changing date.timezone, but I was not aware I was also making use of short tags. When I found 5.6's config checked for short_open_tags, it was off. My 5.5 config shows it on. I feel silly, but I knew it had to be something like that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks like a code problem with quotation marks.
Your echo / print probably has wrong or unescaped quotes somewhere?
Example:

```
<html><?php $var = '"string $text string"; ?></html> // note the extra single quote!
```

This would cause a similar problem to what your picture show.

Comment: I'm sure I'll get flack for this lol, but I do use Dreamweaver which tends to identify these kinds of issues - I will double check though of course, thank you.

Comment: Everyone has their favorite coding software, no arguments here. Found the problem yet?